# how to create a territories on a bing map using MVC4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to the **Bing maps**. I am working on a territory map project.

I have a set of zip codes in  my datatbase, I want the Zip codes to point on a map and  also want to highlight that pointed region to form a territory.

I can point the zip codes but i am unable to draw a territory. Can any one help me on this, or can suggest me any links.